# Rcpp matrix: loop over rows, one column at a time

Tags: r, rcpp

This is my first time trying Rcpp and this very simple problem is giving me trouble. I want to use nested for loops to operate on individual values of a matrix, one column at a time. The script I'm aiming for would look something like this:

```
src <- '
    Rcpp::NumericMatrix Am(A);
    int nrows = Am.nrow();
    int ncolumns = Am.ncol();
    for (int i = 0; i < ncolumns; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j < nrows; j++){
            Am[j,i] = Am[j,i] + Am[j-1,i];
        }
    }
    return Am;
'
fun <- cxxfunction(signature(A = "numeric"), body = src, plugin="Rcpp")
fun(matrix(1,4,4))
```

The desired output would be this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4
```

The problem is obviously in this line, where I don't know how to refer to individual elements of the matrix.

```
Am[j,i] = Am[j,i] + Am[j-1,i];
```

Apologies if this is a stupid newbie question. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: I said it before, I'll say it again:  the `rcpp-devel` is a better place for these questions.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel While I understand that the `rcpp-devel` list might get more exposure to people experienced with `rcpp`, stackoverflow is, in my opinion, much more accessible.

Comment: @jbaums: sure but of all the key rcpp-devel contributors only one sees questions here.  Fewer eyeballs for questions ...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You **cannot** use multiple indices in a single `[ ]` expression. It is a C language restriction that **no** C++ matrix class system or library I know of overcomes. So use `( )` instead.

Fixing that and the mistake that you didn't actually pass `src` to `cxxfunction()`, we get this:

```
R> src <- '
+     Rcpp::NumericMatrix Am(A);
+     int nrows = Am.nrow();
+     int ncolumns = Am.ncol();
+     for (int i = 0; i < ncolumns; i++) {
+         for (int j = 1; j < nrows; j++) {
+             Am(j,i) = Am(j,i) + Am(j-1,i);
+         }
+     }
+     return Am;
+ '
R> fun <- cxxfunction(signature(A = "numeric"), body = src, plugin="Rcpp")
R> fun(matrix(1,4,4))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4
R>
```

Lastly, note that Rcpp sugar has examples for working on entire row or column at a time, see the mailing list archives and vignette.

***Edit:*** Just to be explicit, here is the same using just *one loop* and the column-wise indexing of Rcpp sugar:

```
R> src <- '
+     Rcpp::NumericMatrix Am(A);
+     int nrows = Am.nrow();
+     for (int j = 1; j < nrows; j++) {
+         Am(j,_) = Am(j,_) + Am(j-1,_);
+     }
+     return Am;
+ '
R> fun <- cxxfunction(signature(A = "numeric"), body = src, plugin="Rcpp")
R> fun(matrix(1,4,4))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4
R>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks for the response Dirk. I will direct future questions (if any) to the Rcpp-devel list. Thanks again!

Comment: Instead `Am(j,_)` you can use `Am.row(j)`.